# InteliJ Live Template

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, live

I have a question regarding inteliJ live template , 
i have a member in my class :

```
@JsonProperty("CA_DL_Active_Carriers_NR_SM_DL_UE1")
    private Float caDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1;
```

and i would like to create a getter and setter (custom setter) like this:

```
  public Float getCaDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1() {
        return caDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1;
    }



   public void setCaDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1(Float caDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1) {
        if (Objects.equals(getCaDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1(), caDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1)) {
            return;
        }
        this.caDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1 = caDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1;
        if (DocKind.ORIG == docKind) {
            ((McpttIterationDocument) prepareDirtyDocument()).setCaDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1(caDlActiveCarriersNrSmDlUe1);
        }
```

i created a Live Templeate for the setter :

```
public void set$CAP_SELECTION$(java.lang.Float $SELECTION$) {
        if (java.util.Objects.equals(get$CAP_SELECTION$, $SELECTION$)) {
            return;
        }
        this.$SELECTION$ = $SELECTION$;
        if (com.att.tlv.arc.backend.api.persistence.documents.BaseDocument.DocKind.ORIG == docKind) {
            (($CLASSNAME$) prepareDirtyDocument()).set$CAP_SELECTION$($SELECTION$);
        }
```

[![var settings][1]][1]
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4YPN.png
but my $CAP_SELECTION$ & $SELECTION$ are empty when i applty the custom setter:

can anyone help me undestand what i'm doing wrong ? 
also can i highlight my member (double click it) and apply my seeter ? like clicking "generate" but insted of the regular option ,,, i'll use my live template...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a custom setter it is better to use the `Code | Generate` action. You can add custom getter or setter templates there to create the kind of method you want.

Here's what to do:

1. Invoke `Code | Generate` (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on Mac)
2. Select `Getter and Setter` in the popup that appears
3. Click on the `...` button after the Setter template dropdown
4. Add a new template using the `+` button
5. Add something like the following template text and give it a name:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
#set($methodSuffix = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void set$methodSuffix($field.type $paramName) {
if (java.util.Objects.equals(get$methodSuffix(), $paramName)) {
return;
}
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
    this.##
    #else
        $classname.##
    #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
if (DocKind.ORIG == docKind) {
((McpttIterationDocument) prepareDirtyDocument()).set$methodSuffix($paramName);
}
}
```

You may want to fully qualify the reference to `DocKind` and `McpttIterationDocument`.

6. Click `OK` on the template dialog and click `OK` on the generate getters and setters dialog

Result: a reusable custom setter template.

Comment: this is a perfect solution !!  you are truly a life saver !!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use "Live Template". 
to create ,  property , member , custom getter & setter .

open intelij
click on prefrencess search "live templates"
click +m and add your template.

use the following code below:

@JsonProperty("$SELECTION$")
private $ELEMENT_TYPE$ $TOLOWER$;

```
public $ELEMENT_TYPE$ get$CAP_SELECTION$() {
    return $TOLOWER$;
}

public void set$CAP_SELECTION$($ELEMENT_TYPE$ $TOLOWER$) {
        if (java.util.Objects.equals(get$CAP_SELECTION$(), $TOLOWER$)) {
            return;
        }
        this.$TOLOWER$ = $TOLOWER$;
        if (com.att.tlv.arc.backend.api.persistence.documents.BaseDocument.DocKind.ORIG == docKind) {
            (($CLASSNAME$) prepareDirtyDocument()).set$CAP_SELECTION$($TOLOWER$);
        }


    $END$
```

Use the following [image: variables settings]

see example :

[image: example]

[image: example2]